# Unnecessary styles when using TabPane

Tags: javascript, google-closure, google-closure-library

I have a web tool, where a user can dynamically create and delete multiple tabbed objects (possibly very many), I am using Google Closure TabPane and everything works just fine, except the fact, that each creating of TabPane instance adds the following style line to the bottom of the `<head>` tag:

```
<style>.goog-tabpane-clear { clear: both; height: 0px; overflow: hidden }</style>
```

This line is never deleted. So after working with my tool for a while, the `<head>` tag is swarmed by tens or even hundreds of these lines.

Google Closure is (imho) so professional, so I assume I am doing something wrong rather that thinking that it's the intended way. And if not, is anyone aware of anything more elegant than fixing it the hard way after creation of each instance?

If it helps, I believe that the line is added by function `goog.ui.TabPane.createClear_()`

Comment: I think tabPane is deprecated , use TabBar

Comment: Is it? I haven't found anything about it being deprecated on [this page](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/class_goog_ui_TabPane.html). Where can I verify this?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/closure/goog/ui/tabpane.js#53  line no. 53

Comment: @dekdev Please post your answer so that the question doesn't stay in un unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the source code, `TabPane` is deprecated. Please use [`TabBar`](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/class_goog_ui_TabBar.html) instead